# PHP 7 | MYSQLI Query not fetching only fetching one entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($sql_servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $sql_dbname);

$bets = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id` FROM `betting` WHERE `open`=1"), MYSQLI_NUM);

foreach($bets as $row){
        $bet = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id` FROM `betting` WHERE `id`=$row");
        $hostu = $bet[0];
        $bet_amount = $bet[4];
        echo "
        <br>
        <div style=\"border:1px solid grey;\">
            <span>Bet: $bet_amount Rubies, Opponent (host): $hostu</span><p>id $row</p>
            <button style=\"width: 10%;\" onclick=\"window.location = 'bet.php?id=" . $row ."'\">Bet</button>
        </div>
        ";
    }
```

This code is supposed to select all the ids and give them back to me in an array, but it only fetches one id. When I test
"SELECT `id` FROM `betting` WHERE `id`=$row"
 in phpMyadmin, it returns exactly what i want, but for some reason not in my php code. It echos one id, when i have 4 that are open=1.

Comment: you've only invoked `fetch_array` once, thats why

Comment: Please format your code properly; it's all messed up.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @Terminus Not clear, but most apps eventually involve that in some capacity. I just put it in there as advice since that's the biggest mistake of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch_array function will retrieve the first row only into an array and will move the row pointer forward. What you need to do is step the row pointer through with a loop to return each until the row pointer doesn't find any more rows.

Try the following code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($sql_servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $sql_dbname);

$bets = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM betting WHERE open=1");

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $bets, MYSQL_NUM ) ) { 
    // Do something with your row data
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Essentially what is happening is the while loop is collecting a new instance of $row from the query result and advancing the row pointer forward. When there are no more rows to get - fetch_array will return false ending the loop. -----

Comment: Thanks alot! Life saver :)